# How to convert this YAML into JSON

Tags: json, yaml

I want to convert [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/managing-deployments.md#organizing-resource-configurations) YAML fragment into valid JSON:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-svc
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

How does `---` translate into JSON?

http://yamltojson.com/ does not recognise this YAML as being valid.

Comment: Are you trying to solve this problem once, or are you trying to implement a general solution in a particular language?

Answer (score 1):

Your question didn't indicate if you were trying to solve this in a particular language. Despite what Assaf says, this *is* a valid YAML stream. The YAML spec says:

> A YAML *stream* consists of zero or more documents. Subsequent documents require some sort of separation marker line. If a document is not terminated by a document end marker line, then the following document must begin with a directives end marker line. (http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2801681)

The "directives end marker line" is this: `---`. It's called that because it comes after the directives (e.g. `%YAML 1.2`) at the beginning of a YAML document. But the list of directives may be empty, so `---` by itself is a valid way to indicate the start of a document.

*However*, there's no standard way to represent multiple documents in JSON, so if and how you can accomplish this depends entirely on the API that consumes the JSON file. There are some [common ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Streaming) to represent JSON streams that may or may not work—again, depending on whether or not the API that's consuming the data understands it. For example, this *might* work:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Service",
  // ...
}
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  // ...
}
```

This is called (by some people, anyway) [Line Delimited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Delimited_JSON).

But again, it depends entirely on whether or not the API consuming the data understands this format, which is not a formal or "official" specification. You should consult the API documentation or contact the API's makers to find out the correct way to do what you're trying to do, if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

`---` and `...` may appear at the start and end of a YAML document to indicate its beginning and end, respectively. A quirk of the YAML format.

Thus the snippet you give isn't actually valid YAML. Maybe it's two files that got concatenated.

Comment: And what could be the equivalent JSON if i have to send this concatenated version in one single file to the tool that consume it (in my case it is Kubernetes http://kubernetes.io/)

Comment: The YAML given is absolutely a valid YAML stream. From the spec: "A YAML stream consists of zero or more documents. Subsequent documents require some sort of separation marker line. If a document is not terminated by a document end marker line, then the following document must begin with a directives end marker line." `---` is the "directives end marker line." The list of directives may be empty, so the above YAML is a valid YAML stream. Ruby's `YAML.load_stream` had no trouble with it. Take a look: http://ideone.com/THDnDx